# loop through certain elements inside div

Tags: jquery, for-loop, indexing, jquery-selectors, typeof

I'm having html code like this

```
<div class="myLinks">
  <div class="menu">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <div class="submenu">
    <a href="#">item 1</a>
    <a href="#">item 2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="menu">
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <div class="submenu">
      <a href="#">item 3</a>
      <a href="#">item 4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#">contact</a>
</div>
```

So I have 7 links most of them are inside divs and only 1 link not inside another div which is "Contact". Now I'm trying to give every link an id which equals its index according to other links not all elements inside the main div so I do this

```
var links= $(".myLinks a").length; //7
for(var x=1; x<links; x++){
    var i = x-1;
       $(".myLinks a:eq("+i+")").attr("id",i);
    });
}
```

But this does not work because $(".myLinks a:nth-child("+i+")") is not going to count links only but counts all the items inside .myLinks so i need to give every link an id equals its order among other links

example: http://jsfiddle.net/a67b3emq/

Comment: Why do you want to give each an `id` equal to its index? Why not just access it by index when you need it?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That's what I was thinking. Also, it sounded at the end there that you wanted the `ID` to reset based on it's nested level - that would create duplicate IDs

Comment: because i'll use this id later to connect every link to an action connected to other elements with the same index from another div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `.each()` to achieve the goal here:

```
$(".myLinks a").each(function(i){
   this.id=i;
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qx05m0x9/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot I think I was mistaken looking for the hard way.